# NullPointerException using security-domain in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: ldap, jboss7.x

Here is how I configured my JBoss security domain for LDAP:

```
<security-domain name="LDAPPolicy" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ldap.company.com:389/"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="none"/>
            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
            <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL_SCOPE"/>
            <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=people,dc=company,dc=com"/>
            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

But, when I try to connect, I get this error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8781-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required
at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:270) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:280) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:373) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.naming.NameImpl.<init>(NameImpl.java:264) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at javax.naming.CompositeName.<init>(CompositeName.java:214) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.rolesSearch(LdapExtLoginModule.java:531) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.createLdapInitContext(LdapExtLoginModule.java:445) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.validatePassword(LdapExtLoginModule.java:312) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:267) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    ... 26 more
```

Note: on our LDAP server, suid represents unique ID for each people. uid represents username ("surname name").

Comment: Looks like you are not sending a password. Is that a requirement or a feasible case? if yes then try to rerun your test case by turning the `allowEmptyPasswords` to `true` in your LDAP policy.

Comment: I tried it but it gave me the same result. I use a form with j_security_check, j_username and j_password.